# Haskell functions left-to-right

Tags: haskell, clojure

I have a function that I use quite frequently, which allows me to write my code in a way which seems more natural to me.

```
infixl 6 $:
($:) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
a $: f = f a
```

This lets me do something like

```
let x = getData
        $: sort
        $: group
        $: aggregate
```

instead of

```
let x = aggregate 
        $ group 
        $ sort 
        $ getData
```

I recently learned that Clojure has something like this built in (I don't know much Clojure, but I think it would be written `(-> getData sort group aggregate)`?) which makes me wonder if Haskell has it built in as well. Hoogle [doesn't have any results](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=a+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+b) though.

Are there any standard libs with something similar included? It probably makes my code hard for others to read if I have such a common part is idiosyncratic.

Comment: My preference is to call this operation `#` as per OOHaskell, since it is fundamentally the same operation as method selection on objects and the `#` is the operator used for this in OCaml.  Alternatively, copying F# we could use `|>`

Comment: There was a proposal for introducing `flip ($)` to Data.Function, but it was dropped because no consensus could be reached on whether such a thing would be useful (opposed to confusing to beginners etc.) to have. Here's the discussion: http://markmail.org/message/vsplpb7aajp7goqo?q=python

Comment: Could you accept [Yoann B.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36649412/745903)? The [`&` operator](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:-38-) is by now pretty widely used (presumably, mostly thanks to the highly influential `lens` library, which includes it in its standard coding style).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's nothing like this built in, but [`Control.Category.(>>>)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.0.0/doc/html/Control-Category.html#v%3a-62--62--62-) is close: it's `flip (.)`, so you can write

```
f x = x $: sort $: group $: aggregate
```

as

```
f = sort >>> group >>> aggregate
```

There's [no shortage of definitions and names](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html?query=a%20-%3E%20%28a%20-%3E%20b%29%20-%3E%20b&start=0) for your `($:)` combinator. I think functions tend to suit the pipeline style more often than simple applications, so I don't feel any great need for it; `(>>>)` is a bit ugly, though.

(Besides, Haskell's non-strict semantics mean that the flow of data isn't necessarily in the direction the arrows are pointing here; after all, `aggregate` could provide the first constructor before `sort` even gets a chance to look at the argument. So I tend to just use `(.)` and `($)`; I'm used to the order.)

Comment: Ugly or not I think (>>>) is intuitive because it looks like (>>=), which is a similar left-to-right pipeline.

Comment: Too bad it's `flip (.)` instead of `flip ($)`. But I guess `>>>` is as close as you can get.

Comment: There's also (#) from http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/diagrams-lib/0.4.0.1/doc/html/Diagrams-Util.html , but it has a far different infix precedence than ($).

Answer (score 5):

The reverse application operator your are describing is now part of the standard package `base` (since 4.8.0) as the [`&` operator](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:-38-).

Note that this operator is defined with a lower precedence than the one you proposed (`infixl 1`).

Answer (score 2):

There is a library called Flow (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/flow-1.0.10/docs/Flow.html) available in Hackage, created by Taylor Fausak for this exact demand.

It uses the `|>` operator (inspired from F#) to act as a thread-last.

For eg:

```
3 |> succ |> recip |> negate
-0.25
```